# For clarity's sake should you include everything already included in a .h file in the .cpp file?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have some .h file

random.h

```cpp
#ifndef RANDOM_H
#define RANDOM_H

#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class Random {
  std::vector<std::list<std::string> > m_vectorList;
}

#endif
```

in the corresponding cpp file should I also

```cpp
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
```

so that whoever is working on the implementation doesn't need to look back to the header file, or is it bad practice to include it twice?

Comment: The implementation file will **always** need to look back to the header file, so it's not saving any time.

Comment: @erip Yeah I understand that. If it wasn't clear I meant is it useful so that the programmer working on the project doesn't need to look back at what's been included in the header file.

Comment: "whoever is working on the implementation doesn't need to look back to the header file" — they need to look back to the header file anyway.

Comment: @zenith yeah I figured. Sorry if it came off as a dumb question. It's just been this little thing that's been on my mind for a while.

Comment: The programmer *needs* to look into the header files. Actually, header files are the first files I am looking into when discovering a new program.

Comment: Ah, understood. Different kind of time-saving. :) I don't think there's too much real information to be gleaned from knowing the name of the included headers, though.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Yeah that's the vibe I've basically gotten from everyone myself included. Just was curious if it was done professionally because I've never done any C++ outside of school and personal projects.

Comment: @AR7: then study the source code of large free software (like [Qt](http://qt.io/) or Firefox or [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [LLVM](http://llvm.org/)) which is practically written by professionals working full time or half time on it.

Comment: Do a Google search for Google's "Include what you use" (IWYU) software.  Even if you don't decide to use it, it will give you some ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically there's no point as doing this even as a time saver because:

> The programmer needs to look into the header files. Actually, header files are the first files I am looking into when discovering a new program. -  Basile Starynkevitch

Comment: That is a great quote that will survive the ages.

Comment: @NeilKirk Lol one time I asked on meta what to do if the answer is in the comments, and they just said make it a community wiki since I won't get rep from taking someone else's answer, but yes I think this quote is one for the books.

Answer (score 2):

Not only is it bad practice, it will throw a compiler error if the header files don't have include guards (`#ifndef`/`#define`/`#endif`).

Comment: Right in theory, but in practice *standard* headers *usually* have guards.

Comment: I don't think I've ever used a header that didn't have guards.

Comment: @NeilKirk not even your first program that included your own header file? : )

Comment: That doesn't count !!

Comment: The standard headers are required to be idempotent, so if they are included multiple times, there is no problem.  Sane people make their own headers idempotent too, normally.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining a new header. so you need not include pre defined header twice. It's logical. Although you can include pre defined header either in new header file or .cpp file. Also it will throw a compiler error if you defined it twice because of `#ifdef`  condition.

```
#define 

#ifdef
#endif

#ifndef
     #define
#endif
```